# Pass response from PHP file to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

Basically, after I check in jQuery.post that it's a success, I need to equate the PHP variables I created inside the success part to the response

Example:

```
function(response.success) {
<?php 
global $wpdb;

$table = 'wp_special';
$name = RESPONSE NAME FROM PHP FILE
$email= RESPONSE EMAIL FROM PHP FILE

$wpdb->insert(
    $table,
    array(
        'id' => '',
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
    )
);
?>
}
```

If that won't work, is there a way to insert in the database in my `process.php` file?. Somehow, WordPress won't let me.

Comment: If you want to do something at server side on success response then call AJAX on success response again, Or do it in your `jQuery.post`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the php code is processed on `server-side`, that means once you run this page the php code won't run again calling a javascript function like that, thats only achievable if you use AJAX.

If you have access to the php script that you first `post` to, continue the php process there. If you can't alter that script, create another php script which you will `post` to it after you get the data needed from `response`.